# How to Plot Live Graph from Threading Queue to Multiprocessing with Responsive Window?

Tags: python

I have some program which updates `global` `Dataframe` every few second. I want to `plot` live graph with that `dataframe`.

`Dataframe` updated on `threading`. On internet I found, to `plot` graph with updated `dataframe` we need `multiprocessing.Process` with `Queue`.

**How to keep plot open with responsive window and update if dataframe changed?**

My demo Code:

```
import threading
import time
from multiprocessing import Process,Queue
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
print("Starting")
global df


def live_df():
    global df
    df = pd.DataFrame({"demo": range(10)})
    for n in range(10, 20):
        df = df.append([{"demo": n}], ignore_index=True)
        q.put(df)
        time.sleep(5)
        print("DataFrame Updated:", n)


def live_graph(qq):
    plt.ion()
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    for a in range(30):
        data = qq.get()
        print("inside Graph", a)
        ax.plot(data)
        plt.title(a)
        fig.canvas.draw()
        fig.canvas.flush_events()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    threading.Thread(target=live_df, daemon=True).start()
    p = Process(target=live_graph, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Is this efficient approch or I need some changes? I tried FuncAnimation but with no success.

`Graph plot` is not responding on `time.sleep` inside `demo_df` function, Why?

My OS is Windows.

Comment: Anyone here what i can do?